# How do I get a variable from a dervied class to be used when executing a method from a base class?

Tags: c#, radix, derived-class

I'm trying to use two different derived classes that inherit from a base class, with each of them having a boolean variable that differs from the other. The boolean has been assigned in both the base and the derived classes. However, when I access a method from the derived class that is only declared in the base class, the boolean results in the base class's result.

I already tried executing a method in each class that initializes its declared variables. No change has been made.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public class BaseC : Form
    {
        public bool reversePlace = false;

        public void computeInput(BaseC cc)
        {
            if (reversePlace)
            {
                //Execute condition
                if (cc.reversePlace)
                {
                    //Execute execution from other derived class
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public class DerivedC1 : BaseC
    {
        public bool reversePlace = true;
    }

    public class DerivedC2 : BaseC
    {
        public bool reversePlace = false;
    }

    DerivedC1 C1 = new DerivedC1();
    DerivedC2 C2 = new DerivedC2();

    public Form2()
    {
        C1.computeInput(C2); //Should execute first condition for being true while ignoring the inner condtion for being false
    }

}
```

I should be getting an if statement from C1 halfway complete while skipping the if condition for C2. C1's boolean should be true while C2's should be false. However, both booleans are instead regarded as false.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a virtual property. When it's virtual and overridden, even code defined in the base class will look at the most-overridden property of the current instance.

```
public class BaseC : Form
{
    public virtual bool ReversePlace => false;
    //etc....
}


public class DerivedC1 : BaseC
{
    public override bool ReversePlace => true;
}

public class DerivedC2 : BaseC
{
    public override bool ReversePlace => false;
}
```

Comment: I actually tried that earlier, but it wasn't working. I see that I have to include a lambda expression (=>) in order to complete the assignment. But now how do I update the boolean once more within each class? It seems this method only works upon declaring the variable.

Comment: There is no assignment in the subclasses. The `=> true` in one of the subclasses is a shorthand for  `{ return true; }`.

Comment: So how do I then switch C1 to false when needed?

Answer (score 0):

I would take some time to look into inheritance, specifically things like virtual properties and methods, and how to override them.

Your base class should generally be using the keyword virtual and overriding when necessary for child methods and classes.

Here is a link to help you get the general idea: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/virtual-method-in-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to set the value, not hide the inherited member from the base class, you can do so in the constructors.

```
...

public class DerivedC1 : BaseC
{
    public DerivedC1()
    {
        this.reversePlace = true;
    }
}

public class DerivedC2 : BaseC
{
    public DerivedC2()
    {
        this.reversePlace = false;
    }
}

...
```